# What does this declared vector in C++ mean?

Tags: c++, vector, macros, typedef

I'm fairly new to C++, so I'm having a hard time understanding some complex terms such as Macros and Preprocessors. The code that I can't understand is attached below:

```
#define NP 2
#define MAX 2000

typedef pair<int, double> edge;

vector<edge> vec[NP][MAX];
```

What I can't understand here is, what does the vector really store and what does [NP][MAX] determine?

Comment: I'll ask you -- What does `int vec[NP][MAX];` mean?  If you know what that means, what is the issue in figuring out `vector<edge> vec[NP][MAX];`?

Comment: The whole thing expands to `vector<pair<int, double>> vec[2][2000]`. Simply put, a 2 dimensional array of vectors.

Comment: I would like to mention that macros should be prevented in C++. Macro identifiers are not subject of `namespace`s which can cause strange effects where they are not expected. In this case, `const` integral variables would do as well.

Comment: The `MAX` also seems to indicate that the two array components really should be `vector`/`array` as well, e.g. `vector<vector<vector<edge>>>` or `vector<array<vector<edge>, NP>>`. `vector` handles arrays of varying size correctly, there is no need to limit the program by introducing a maximum size and manually tracking the actual size.

Comment: @RokasVišinskas y u answer in the comments

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica because I don't really feel this is worthy of an actual answer.

Comment: @RokasVišinskas Then feel free to not answer it, but then doing so in the comments section instead is double-bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not "a vector" — there are many vectors. Many!

Just as `int foo[5]` creates an array of five `int`s, and `int foo[5][10]` creates a two-dimensional array of fifty `int`s total…

… `vector<edge> vec[5][10]` creates an array of fifty `vector<edge>`s.

Now add on the macros: that's just text substitution (more or less), so the array dimensions are being provided via a constant name rather than right there as numbers in the declaration.

So it's a `vector<edge> vec[2][2000]`, or four thousand `vector<edge>`s.

The type `edge` is an alias for `pair<int, double>` (thanks, `typedef`!), so it's really:

```
vector<pair<int, double>> vec[2][2000].
```

This is probably not what was actually intended. Though there is nothing illegal about arrays of vectors, they're a bit of a "double-positive". The vector is already an array-like thing, and it seems likely that the author wanted to create a sort of "two-dimensional vector", but did it wrong. We cannot know this for sure, though, without asking them.

Comment: @Caleth: Haha oh yeah. I think I was going to make it `[5][5]` ... then, like, didn't. 